# Why does JPA do a double insert upon merge()

Tags: jpa, merge, eclipselink

In EclipseLink, I run into a problem where an element is inserted twice, resulting into a primary key violation. The scenario is as follows:
I have three entities, Element, Restriction and RestrictionElement. The entity RestrictionElement acts as a many-to-many relationship between the two others.
When I create a new RestrictionElement and merge the Element, the RestrictionElement is inserted twice. The code:

```
// element is an Element, restriction is a Restriction. Both are already in present in the database.
RestrictionElement newRestrictionElement = new RestrictionElement(restriction, element);
Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
em.merge(element); //em is the EntityManager
transaction.commit();
```

However, if I remove the line `restriction.getReferencedRestrictionElements().add(this);` the RestrictionElement is inserted once. 
Can anyone explain why this happens? Or point to a document that explains how to work out what the merge() command does?

Relevant JPA code: (I'll only given a small part. There aren't any other big problems with the code.)

```
public class RestrictionElement {

    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "ELEMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),@JoinColumn(name = "ELEMENT_DESCRIPTOR", referencedColumnName = "DESCRIPTOR")})
    private Element element;

    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "RESTRICTION_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),@JoinColumn(name = "RESTRICTION_DESCRIPTOR", referencedColumnName = "DESCRIPTOR")})
    private Restriction restriction;

    public RestrictionElement(Restriction restriction, Element element) {
        this.restriction = restriction;
        this.element = element;
        restriction.getReferencedRestrictionElements().add(this);
        element.getReferingRestrictionElements().add(this);
    }
}

public class Element {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "element")
    private List<RestrictionElement> referingRestrictionElements = new ArrayList<RestrictionElement>();
}

public class Restriction extends Element {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restriction", cascade = { ALL, PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE, REFRESH })
    private List<RestrictionElement> referencedRestrictionElements = new ArrayList<RestrictionElement>();
}
```

Comment: In your code in RestrictionElement, I cannot see you have declared the nature of the relationship (i.e. @OneToOne, @ManyToOne, etc). Am I missing something here?

Comment: The real code doesn't contain it, and for the most part, it works, so apparently it isn't necessary.

Comment: This is not a matter of taste, this is part of the [JPA specification](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317). Besides, it is in these annotations where you define the merging behavior of a given association. You even have OneToMany mapping an non-existing relationship on the other side of the binary association. If I were you, I'd fix this first, and then see if the problem persists, but until the entities are not properly annotated, no one can be sure why things do not behave as expected. Your question here is why your code does not work, so you should not underestimate this.

Answer (score 2):

How do your persist RestrictionElement?  My guess is when you persist it you get one copy, then a second when you merge the Element with the reference to it.

Try using persist() for new objects, and related the objects after they are managed with the correct managed copy.

Comment: I don't explicitly persist RestrictionElement. Unfortunately, persisting new objects would require a large refactoring, a step we're unwilling to take at this stage in the project (it's soon going to be retired...)

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar issue when I run my program, but the issue is not there under step by step debugging.

I resolved the issue by changing List to Set in the OneToMany relationship.

Comment: I had to remove `final` and initializing the field to a new collection.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that once you retrieve an instance of the class using JPA, the instance becomes managed, any changes to it will be automatically merged into the database.

By default, this merge will occur at the moment you query the table. Therefore the following situation can happen:

- query (find by ID)
- update (setName = "xx")
- query another class that has a direct relationship to this one (find by ID again)

in a situation similar to the above, the second find will effectively issue a merge to the first table. (I'm not sure exactly of the details or scenarios here).

My suggestion is that you issue every single query (findById for example) or every instance you have before you start modifying it (ie, set, etc).

Hope it helps.